# Perl Excel::Writer::XLSX for adding a chart

Tags: perl

I am using the [`Excel::Writer::XLSX`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Excel::Writer::XLSX) module to create a spreadsheet which works fine.  However, when I try to add a chart, I keep getting an error about an Unkown worksheet reference.  I won't post the entire script but I have my workbook and worksheet defined

```
my $workbook = Excel::Writer::XLSX->new( $xlsxgood );
my $worksheet = $workbook->add_worksheet( "$sheetname" );
```

Then I do all the worksheet writes to fill out the spreadsheet which works fine.  The following is the code I wanted to use to fill out the chart.  I have the date in the 2nd column, and all the data to chart in columns 3,4 and 5.

```
my $chart = $workbook->add_chart( type => 'column', embedded => 1 );

# Configure the first series. (Sample 1)
$chart->add_series(
    name   => '=Sheet1!$A$0',
    values => '=Sheet1!$B$2:$B$15',
);

# Add a chart title and some axis labels.
$chart->set_title( name => 'Results of sample analysis' );
$chart->set_x_axis( name => 'Date' );
$chart->set_y_axis( name => 'Values' );

# Insert the chart into the worksheet (with an offset).
$worksheet->insert_chart( 'R2', $chart, 25, 10 );
```

The answer I get back is:

```
Unknown worksheet reference 'Sheet1' in range 'Sheet1!$A$0' passed to add_series().
```

Answer (score 1):

The error warning means that you are using a formula in the chart series that refers to a worksheet named `Sheet1` but you haven't added a worksheet with that name.

Also `$A$0` isn't a valid cell. That should be corrected as well.